# property 'findIndex' of undefined

Tags: .net, angular, web-applications

Hello I got a problem in this piece of code:

```
private addOrUpdateItemInCompare(items: ICompareItem[], itemToAdd: ICompareItem, quantity: number): ICompareItem[] {
    const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === itemToAdd.id);
    if(index === -1){
      itemToAdd.quantity = quantity;
      items.push(itemToAdd);

    }
    else{
      items[index].quantity += quantity;
    }

    return items;
}
```

When I try to use this method I got an error

> "Cannot read property 'findIndex' of undefined"

I have no idea where is a problem, because in a method similar to the 1st:

```
private addOrUpdateItemInBasket(items: IBasketItem[], itemToAdd: IBasketItem, quantity: number): IBasketItem[] {
    const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id === itemToAdd.id);
    if(index === -1){
      itemToAdd.quantity = quantity;
      items.push(itemToAdd);

    }
    else{
      items[index].quantity += quantity;
    }

    return items;
}
```

All is working.

Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: Can you show us the snippet where the function `addOrUpdateItemInCompare` is being called?

Answer (score 0):

Your `items` array value has either `undefined` or `null`. Please make sure your `items` have a value.

Comment: i check it and yes items-IComareItems are undefined but when i check it, it should be                         
export interface ICompare {
    id: string;
    items: ICompareItem[];
    clientSecret?: string;
  }

export  interface ICompareItem {
    id: number;
  productName: string;
  price: number;
  pictureUrl: string;
  brand: string;
  type: string;
  stock: number;
  colour: string;
  material: string;
  dimensions: string;
  quantity: number;
  }
export class Compare implements ICompare {
    id = uuidv4();
    items: ICompareItem[];
}

Comment: if possible can you reproduce this in stackblitz.com?

Comment: It is a lot of work but I can share this code with you on GitHub